# Why does resizing a label require a delay to update as expected when coming from NotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uikit, uilabel

I'm in the process of adding dynamic type to my app and I'm trying to update the frame of a programmatically created UILabel when the `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` notification is fired through the following code:

```
private func configureNotificationCenter() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(contentSizeCategoryDidChange) , name: NSNotification.Name("UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
}

@objc private func contentSizeCategoryDidChange() {
    self.delegate?.didChangeContentSize()
}
```

and then in the view where the UILabel is going to be updated, I update the frame:

```
func didChangeContentSize() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
        self.label.sizeToFit()
    })
}
```

For some reason, the frame is not set properly without calling `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter ...`. At first, I tried calling `DispatchQueue.main` without the 0.1 second delay since I know UI updates should always be on the main thread, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

While delaying 0.1 seconds isn't a huge deal and I don't think any users would notice, it would be great to understand what's going on and why the delay is necessary.

Edit: Here's how I'm creating the label

```
label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: 200))
label.backgroundColor = .red
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.text = "Test title that should resize"
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
label.textAlignment = .center

let userFont =  UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .title1)
let pointSize = userFont.pointSize
let customFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: pointSize)
label.font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: customFont!)

label.sizeToFit()
view.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: Have you tried `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`? It _might_ do the trick for your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds very much like an *Auto Layout* issue.  When you don't delay, *Auto Layout* is adjusting the intrinsic size of the label and running after you modify the frame for the label, so your `sizeToFit` comes too early and uses the previous intrinsic size.

When you delay by 0.1 seconds, *Auto Layout* runs first and sets the intrinsic size of the label, and then your  `sizeToFit()` call uses that new intrinsic size to set the frame.

---

**Use Auto Layout**

Make things easier on yourself by using *Auto Layout*.  Instead of messing with `frame` sizes, `sizeToFit`, and notifications, just set constraints for the leading, trailing, and top edges of your label and *Auto Layout* will automatically resize your label when the font size changes:

```
label = UILabel()
label.backgroundColor = .red
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.text = "Test title that should resize"
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
label.textAlignment = .center

let userFont =  UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .title1)
let pointSize = userFont.pointSize
let customFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: pointSize)
label.font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: customFont!)

view.addSubview(label)

label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Weirdly enough I'm already creating the label programmatically. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: Update the code to show the creation of the label.  Also, where are you updating the text of the label that makes the resize necessary?

Comment: I just edited my question to show the creation of the label. The text does not change, `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification` gets called when the user changes their font size preferences from Settings.

Comment: Does it work to call `self.label.layoutSubviews()` before calling `self.label.sizeToFit()` ?

Comment: Nope, not without the delay :/

Comment: One more thing to try:  `self.view.layoutSubviews()` before `self.label.sizeToFit()`.

Comment: It still sizes incorrectly. I also tried it with a textview and ran into the same issue. It seems like it's sizing one size behind? So for example if I set the size to the max possible font, and then the min possible font, the current frame will be the maximum size, but the font will be the smallest font.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show an easier way with *Auto Layout*.  I know your problem behind the scenes is *Auto Layout* and that there is probably a way to get it to work, *but* a much easier way is to embrace *Auto Layout*.  Then you don't have to mess with the notifications at all.

Comment: Thanks for that! I agree, using Auto Layout is definitely the way to go. I'm still curious why I would need to add a 0.1 second delay when setting the frame so I'm going to leave the question open for a couple more days before accepting your answer.